# AVPlayer unable to play m3u8 file if there is any space in the file path

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am doing the HLS experiment in my iOS App.
Please find my below sample .m3u8 file. The first one "480/1.005 Program Management1351620000001 200055 mp4 v4.m3u8" not playing. I am assuming because of the white space it's not playing.

Is there any way to fix the things by setting up/changing any configuration in the AVPlayer?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio-0",NAME="Default",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES,URI="audio/1.005_Program_Management1351620000001-200071_m4a_v4.m3u8"
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=6903000,CODECS="avc1.42001e",URI="480/1.005 Program Management1351620000001 200055 mp4 iframe.m3u8"
#EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=9204000,CODECS="avc1.42001e",URI="720/1.005_Program_Management1351620000001-200045_mp4_iframe.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=451000,RESOLUTION=400x224,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio-0"
480/1.005 Program Management1351620000001 200055 mp4 v4.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=492000,RESOLUTION=480x270,CODECS="avc1.42001e,mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio-0"
720/1.005_Program_Management1351620000001-200045_mp4_v4.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=291000,CODECS="mp4a.40.5",AUDIO="audio-0"
audio/1.005_Program_Management1351620000001-200071_m4a_v4.m3u8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but when I do about video live streaming. If you want to play on iOS, your video must follow standard from Apple (H264). Otherwise, you must you your player instead of using AVPlayer. In Android may be it can be played very well.